# Divisor and Riemann Zeta functions series proofs

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Where d(n) is the number of divisors of n, show that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n)z^n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{1-z^k}$

where both sides converge for |z|<1

and show that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)}{n^s} = (ζ(s))^2$

I've tried playing around with various forms of the divisor function and the Riemann Zeta function, but I can't seem to get anywhere with the first part of the problem. I would really appreciate some help getting started

Answer (score 5):

In $|z|<1$,
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\sum_{j\geq 1}z^{kj} = \sum_{n\geq 1} d(n)\, z^n.$$
For almost the same reason:
$$\zeta(s)^2=\sum_{n,m\geq 1}\frac{1}{(nm)^s}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{d(k)}{k^s}.$$

Comment: (+1) Your answer for the second problem is more in keeping with the idea of the first. I saw the relation with the product formula for $d(n)$ and went with that. It's nice to have more than one approach.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is pretty simple if we expand the geometric series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty z^{jk}\tag{1}
$$
Thus, $z^n$ appears in $(1)$ with a coefficient which is the number of ways we can write $n=jk$, which is $d(n)$.

The second one is a little trickier
$$
\begin{align}
\zeta(s)^2
&=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac1{(1-p^{-s})^2}\\
&=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+1)p^{-ks}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
If $n=\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}}p^{e_p}$, then $d(n)=\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}}(e_p+1)$. Computing the coefficient of $n^{-s}$ in $(2)$ gives $d(n)$, therefore,
$$
\zeta(s)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d(n)}{n^s}\tag{3}
$$